# Ihave installed seahorse and want to change my keyring password. However the old keyring passwird is corrupted( not available). How ro I proceed?

Tags: password, keyrings

I have installed seahorse and want to change my keyring password. However the old keyring password is corrupted( not available). How do I proceed?